# Shopify REST API - how to connect?

Tags: php, curl, shopify

Seems like a simple task but despite having read their docs I can't figure it out. I've gotten a Storefront Access Token, as per https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/getting-started. Then I've used it in the CURL request below. However this just returns: {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}

I found their documentation a bit confusing as they have quite a few different APIs, and whilst it seems that this Storefront Access Token should work for this particular API, perhaps it doesn't?

```
 $url = "https://mysite.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/products/count.json";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $headers = array(
        'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token: 2400d...........a999'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r( $result);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It looks like you get the wrong key no matter how I see. Or have you check the right scope needed to do that request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Stronfront API your request should point to

`https://mysite.myshopify.com/api/2019-07/products/count.json`

and not to

`https://mysite.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/products/count.json`

In addition Storefront Api request are different from the standard ones, have that in mind.